# PHP not working in xampp, accessing through localhose

Tags: php, xampp

```
<html>
 <head>
  <title>PHP Test</title>
 </head>
 <body>

 <?php 

$hfhf = 1;
$dd = 2;
echo( $hfhf + $dd );

 ?> 
 </body>
</html>
```

The above is saved as index.php in htdocs folder. I access it at http://localhost/index.php

The page is blank. When i view source I see exactly the code above.

Is there some setting I need to change in php.ini or xampp?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: it's working fine for me..you start your xampp?

Comment: I discovered it is working on my desktop but not my laptop. Just installed xampp on both a couple of day ago. Maybe windows firewall issue? I would think this would prevent me from accessing http://localhost/index.php . Very odd. Desktop is windows 7 laptop windows 10.

Comment: are your file is "file.html or  file.php "?

Comment: UPDATE: php has now stopped working on my desktop. appache working fine. php was working until i rebooted my computer. or something else caused it. not working on two computers now. my files are .php.

Comment: chrome is adding changing <?php to <!--?php . I wonder why?